# Monitoring for Commons DBCP?

Tags: monitoring, apache-commons-dbcp

A huge webapp in my Tomcat sometimes starts using too many DBCP connections, leading to problems.
To investigate, I want to know precisely at each point in time what thread/method is holding a connection of the pool. Does not need to be real-time, post-mortem analysis is OK.

I have been looking for such a DBCP monitoring tool, in vain, so I am about to write mine.
*(if there is any interest I can make it open source)*

Here is my plan:

- Modify [PoolingDataSource.getConnection](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/PoolingDataSource.java#PoolingDataSource.getConnection%28%29) to log "`DBCP+1 <thread-id>`"
- Modify [DelegatingConnection.close](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/DelegatingConnection.java#DelegatingConnection.close%28%29) to log "`DBCP-1 <thread-id>`"
- Write a small script to generate this simple CSV for visualization:

[image: DBCP monitoring]

QUESTION:
Am I missing some Commons-DBCP 1.4 concept that makes the idea invalid?
Or am I re-inventing the wheel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There was no such tool, so I created it:

https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Commons-DBCP-monitoring

It monitors Commons DBCP usage (using/waiting for connection) and allows one to create such graphs:

[image]

[image]

I [asked](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/commons-user/201208.mbox/%3CCAHCKxyd3p+R6nbUPbk2dpNo7rzwJRDFvPOubJ1V6Y6NGHb3XcA@mail.gmail.com%3E) whether my assumptions are valid on the Commons DBCP mailing list.